Ubuntu Server 22.04 won't upgrade, does not see 24.04 LTS
I checked /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and it should accept LTS upgrades
sudo apt dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

andre@ODIN:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 

I did update/upgrade, and --fix-broken install

The upgrade path from 22.04 LTS is still unstable thus the -d is required; if it's an upgrade to 24.04 you're after, 24.04.1 has not yet been released; having been pushed back now due to blocker bugs visible on the tracker (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/46972)   The command do-release-upgrade is for release-upgrades where 22.04 will go to 24.04(.1) when deemed stable, but currently there are no supported paths except to via message (part of which you didn't paste)
